# Anyway to avoid PostSharp's integration into Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postsharp

I've added PostSharp (strictly for logging methods) to my project, which is a part of a solution along with 4 other projects.

Now it seems like every time any developer on the team needs to touch any part of that solution and compile it, PostSharp comes up with its UI and forces the developer to install their integration tools and just generally confuses everybody.

Is there a way to set it up so that no developers have to deal with it - e.g. just like any other Nuget package.

Comment: When you added it initially, was it as an extension (Tools -> Extensions and Updates...) or as a dependency (Solution -> Manage NuGet packages for solution, or similar)?

Comment: @PaulHicks as a dependency.  But in reality, it then forces you to install the extension.

Comment: Are you sure you added it as a dependency? I just created a new project+solution, right-clicked on the solution, selected "Manage NuGet packages for Soluion...", and added PostSharp to my solution. I didn't get the usual extension-added dialogs. I don't have the PostSharp menu items. I have PostSharp in my project References. It seems to have added it only as a dependency, as you would like it to be.

Comment: I've just reviewed the .csproj file and the only interesting thing I can see is that the project's main `PropertyGroup` has `<DontImportPostSharp>True</DontImportPostSharp>`. Let me see if I can figure out how to set that to True for projects that have it set to False initially.

Comment: I can't find a way to do it automatically. You may have to edit your .csproj files and set `DontImportPostSharp` to `True`.

Comment: `DontImportPostSharp` property is not related to VS extension installation however. It's added mainly for backward compatibility with PostSharp 2.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of PostShapr version 4.3 you're not required to have the Visual Studio extension installed. During your first build with PostSharp it will ask you to install VS extension, but you can reject and select "Never ask me again" option.